# I am looking to call a JS Function inside a Razor function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking to call a JS function inside of a Razor function but I am unable to find the right syntax for it.  I am not sure if I need to reorder my  placement but I do not think it is necessary.

I have tried calling it as a new object and passing that into to the .Action() function but I could not get that to work.  I am not super familiar with JS and if you could explain your answer that would be very appreciated!

```
@Html.Action("MonthlyPSAGauge", "Display", DropDownValue())
function DropDownValue() {
    var value = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    return { selectProductionLine: value };
    }
```

I want to pass the DropDownValue() value into the MonthlyPSAGauge method in the Display Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that will not work, C# is server side and JS (in this case) is client side. To make C# "call" a js function you could use something similar to this.

```
@Html.Raw(<script>DropDownValue();</style>);
```

Which would paste this into the html and would be run on the clients machine, I hope this helps!

Comment: Would I be able to store that JS function return in a variable and just pass it in that way?

Comment: No, when you use @Html.Action, you are telling the server to run the next bit of code **before** sending the files to the clients browser. The JS will then be run on the clients machine hence no data can be passed back. If you need to run code on the server, do it in C#.